# Setting Location of Labels VB.Net

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, label

Here I am reading from an Sql database bringing in a set amount of questions, everything is working fine when retrieving them from the database.

I want each label to be for example 50px below the previous one, at the minute they are all getting set on top of each other and I couldn't find anything on this subject.

All help is very welcome.

```
Private Sub PopulateQuestions()

    Dim Rows As Integer
    Rows = dsQuestionnaire.Tables("Questions").Rows.Count()
    For x = 1 To Rows
        drQuestions = dsQuestionnaire.Tables("Questions").Rows.Find(x)
        Dim lblQuestion As Label = New Label

        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position) = "Absolute"
        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top) = "650px"
        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left) = "50px"

        lblQuestion.Width = 512
        lblQuestion.Text = drQuestions("Question").ToString()
        Me.Controls.Add(lblQuestion)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You're specifically setting the location of them each the same. Make the .Top value some base number of pixels plus 50*x or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I feel pretty silly now.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Private Sub PopulateQuestions()

    Dim Rows As Integer
    Rows = dsQuestionnaire.Tables("Questions").Rows.Count()
    Dim top As Integer
    top = 625
    For x = 1 To Rows
        drQuestions = dsQuestionnaire.Tables("Questions").Rows.Find(x)
        Dim lblQuestion As Label = New Label

        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position) = "Absolute"
        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top) = top & "px"
        lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left) = "50px"
        top += 30

        lblQuestion.Width = 512
        lblQuestion.Text = drQuestions("Question").ToString()
        Me.Controls.Add(lblQuestion)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: As you can see, that solution works, but you could also remove all references to top and just write: lblQuestion.Style(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top) = 625 + 30 * x & "px" which would save you three lines. It's merely stylistic, but something you should *get* as an option.